# Distributing values of a dictionary between keys in another dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

There is a dictionary like this:

```
cap_dict = {Timestamp('2020-06-30 00:00:00'): 40000, Timestamp('2020-09-30 00:00:00'): 52000, 
            Timestamp('2020-12-31 00:00:00'): 52000, Timestamp('2021-03-31 00:00:00'): 58000, 
            Timestamp('2021-06-30 00:00:00'): 89000, Timestamp('2021-09-30 00:00:00'): 89000
            }
```

I am going to create a dictionary (called `daily_cap`) which has daily keys between `date(2020, 6, 28)` and `date(2022, 1, 2)` (or any given date) and the values from above dictionary. In `daily_cap` each of the keys should use the value of the latest available month before itself. For example, `40000` should be allocated to keys from `Timestamp('2020-06-30 00:00:00')` to `Timestamp('2020-09-29 00:00:00')` and `52000` should be allocated to keys from `Timestamp('2020-09-30 00:00:00')` to `Timestamp('2021-03-30 00:00:00')`.
There is another problem in the first element of `cap_dict`. As I mentioned, the `daily_cap` dictionary starts from `date(2020, 6, 28)` (or any given date) while the first element of `cap_dict` is `Timestamp('2020-06-30 00:00:00')`. Each day before the first element of `cap_dict` should get the first element of `cap_dict` in this situation. For example, values for the `Timestamp('2020-06-28 00:00:00')` and `Timestamp('2020-06-29 00:00:00')` should be `40000`.
How can I create the `daily_cap` dictionary?

I tried this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, DAILY


start_date = date(2020, 6, 28)
end_date = date(2022, 1, 2)

cap_dict = {Timestamp('2020-06-30 00:00:00'): 40000, Timestamp('2020-09-30 00:00:00'): 52000, 
            Timestamp('2020-12-31 00:00:00'): 52000, Timestamp('2021-03-31 00:00:00'): 58000, 
            Timestamp('2021-06-30 00:00:00'): 89000, Timestamp('2021-09-30 00:00:00'): 89000
            }

i = 0
daily_cap = {}
val_list = list(cap_dict.values())

for day in rrule(DAILY, dtstart=start_date, until=end_date):
    t = pd.Timestamp(day)
    if t not in cap_dict.keys():
        acceptable_value = val_list[0+i]
        val = acceptable_value
        daily_cap.update({t: val})
        i += 1
    else:
        daily_cap.update({t: cap_dict[t]})
        i += 1

print(daily_cap)
```

The above code does not work correctly since the length of `val_list` and days between `start_date` and `end_date` are not the same.
The output should be like this:

```
daily_cap = {Timestamp('2020-06-28 00:00:00'): 40000, 
             Timestamp('2020-06-29 00:00:00'): 40000, 
             Timestamp('2020-06-30 00:00:00'): 40000,
             Timestamp('2020-07-01 00:00:00'): 40000, 
             .
             .
             .
             Timestamp('2021-04-27 00:00:00'): 58000,
             Timestamp('2021-04-28 00:00:00'): 58000,
             Timestamp('2021-04-29 00:00:00'): 58000,
             .
             .
             .
             Timestamp('2021-09-30 00:00:00'): 89000, 
             Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'): 89000,
             Timestamp('2021-10-02 00:00:00'): 89000
             }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a pandas series from your dict with the new range as index then use `ffill` and `bfill`:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

start_date = date(2020, 6, 28)
end_date = date(2022, 1, 2)

cap_dict = {pd.Timestamp('2020-06-30 00:00:00'): 40000, pd.Timestamp('2020-09-30 00:00:00'): 52000, 
            pd.Timestamp('2020-12-31 00:00:00'): 52000, pd.Timestamp('2021-03-31 00:00:00'): 58000, 
            pd.Timestamp('2021-06-30 00:00:00'): 89000, pd.Timestamp('2021-09-30 00:00:00'): 89000
            }

date_range = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='D')
daily_series = pd.Series(cap_dict, index=date_range).ffill().bfill()
```

`daily_series.to_dict()` will give you:

```
{Timestamp('2020-06-28 00:00:00', freq='D'): 40000.0,
 Timestamp('2020-06-29 00:00:00', freq='D'): 40000.0,
...
 Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:00:00', freq='D'): 89000.0,
 Timestamp('2022-01-02 00:00:00', freq='D'): 89000.0}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code works correctly. Would you tell me how can I convert `Timestamp('2020-06-28 00:00:00', freq='D'): 40000.0` to `Timestamp('2020-06-28 00:00:00'): 40000.0`?

Comment: You don't need conversion here, they're the same objects.